# Show the fixed point function is differentiable to parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I have a complete metric space $(S,||_{\infty})$ where $S$ is a space of bounded and Lipschitz continuous function that is defined in $x \in [0,1]$.

Suppose I have $s \in S$ satisfying the following equation :

$$ s(x) = \alpha \cdot (F\circ s) (x)$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$ where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $F:S\rightarrow S$.

One thing that I know is $ T(\alpha,s)  \equiv \alpha \cdot (F\circ s)  : (0,1) \times S \rightarrow S$ is a contraction mapping satisfying

$$ ||T(\alpha,u) - T(\alpha,v)  ||_{\infty} < \beta || u-v||_{\infty}  $$

for any $u,v \in S$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ where $\beta \in (0,1)$.

I am trying to get sufficient conditions that $s(x)$ and $s'(x)$, which is defined almost everywhere by Lipschitz continuity, are both differentiable at least at some $x$ with respect to $\alpha$.

My initial approach was to use contraction mapping theorem with parameter, but I still think that it's overshooting.

I could find some references,  but, unlike my problem where the parameter is just simply multiplied in front of $F$, it discusses in any $T(\alpha,s)$. Having very scant knowledge about functional analysis and topological space, I was wondering if there would be a more straightforward way to show the differentiability.

Comment: If $s=\alpha F(s)$ then $ds/d\alpha=F(s)+\alpha\langle DF(s), ds/d\alpha\rangle$ so $\langle \text{id}-\alpha DF(s), ds/d\alpha\rangle=F(s)$. It looks like you need a Fréchet derivative $DF(s)$ with $\left(\text{id}-\alpha DF(s)\right)$ invertible.

Comment: Hi Ali, it's again you :). Thank you very much again for the comment. I will think more into that direction and update my posting !

Comment: Yes I realised I'd attempted answers for two or three of your questions already and started to wonder what it was all about . BTW I don't think the notation $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is standard in operator theory, I must have made it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Fréchet derivative $A=DF(s)$,
it follows from $s= \alpha F(s)$ that we need
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{ds}{d\alpha} = F(s)+ \alpha A \frac{ds}{d\alpha}
\qquad\qquad (*).
\end{equation*}
Now for any $u$
$$\lVert F(s+\lambda u) - F(s) \rVert \le
\lVert F(s+\lambda u)- F(s)-\lambda A u\rVert
+ \lVert \lambda A  u \rVert
$$
and as a result
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\lVert F(s+\lambda u) - F(s) \rVert}{\lambda \lVert u\rVert}
  -\frac{\lVert Au \rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}
  \le \frac{\lVert F(s+\lambda u)- F(s)-\lambda A u\rVert}{\lambda \lVert u\rVert}.
\end{equation*}
The RHS tends to $0$ as $\lambda\to 0$ (definition of a Fréchet derivative)
so
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\lVert Au \rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}
  = \lim_{\lambda\to 0}
  \frac{\lVert F(s+\lambda u) - F(s) \rVert}{\lambda \lVert u\rVert}
  \le \frac{\beta \lVert s+\lambda u - s\rVert}{\lambda \lVert u\rVert}
  \le 1.
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
  \lVert A \rVert = \sup_{u} \frac{\lVert A u \rVert}{\lVert u \rVert}\le 1.
\end{equation*}
Now let
\begin{equation*}
  \phi(v)=F(s)+\alpha A v
\end{equation*}
which is itself a contraction mapping since
\begin{equation*}
  \lVert \phi(v_{1}) - \phi(v_{2}) \rVert
  =\lVert \alpha A(v_{1}-v_{2})\rVert
  \le \alpha \lVert A \rVert \lVert v_{1}-v_{2} \rVert
  \le \alpha  \lVert v_{1}-v_{2} \rVert.
\end{equation*}
Its fixed point is the unique fn to satisfy $(*)$ so we conclude
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{ds}{d\alpha}=\text{f.p. }\phi.
\end{equation*}